# Python local class leak

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, closures, inner-classes

Would this leak the outer class object ?

```
class Base:
    def AppendToMenu(self,menu,window,data): pass
    def Execute(self,event): pass

class Outer(Base):

    def AppendToMenu(self,menu,window,data):
        if len(data) == 1:
                _leak = self # ?
                class _Inner(Base):        
                    def Execute(self, event):
                        _leak.Execute(event)

                cl = _Inner()
                cl.AppendToMenu(menu,window,data)
        # else...

    def Execute(self,event): self.handle(event)
```

Would then this be ok?

```
class Outer(Base):    
    def AppendToMenu(self,menu,window,data):
        if len(data) == 1:
                class _Inner(Base):
                    def __init__(self, outer):
                        self.outer = outer
                    def Execute(self, event):
                        self.outer.Execute(event)

                cl = _Inner(self)
                cl.AppendToMenu(menu,window,data)
```

Coming from Java so new to closures.

Comment: Why would this leak?

Comment: Nesting Python classes does not have any special meaning, not like in Java.

Comment: `_leak` in `_Inner.Execute()` is a closure, yes, but it won't keep that closure 'live' indefinitely. The reference is cleared once the method exits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: say I create many Outer instances and append them - so many _Inner classes are created - what is the Inner class objects scope ?

Comment: Off-topic, but please see [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: the `_Inner` class is a local in `AppendToMenu`, but any instances you create of it will create references to the class and keep it alive. All Python object lifetimes are determined by such references. You only ever seem to use `_Inner` and its instances as locals in `Outer.AppendToMenu`, so their lifetime is limited.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: so the _Inner class object is destroyed on exiting Outer.Append ? Just not clear to me. No need for the second variation ? Even stylistically ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: on what exactly ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: `cl` is a local in `AppendToMenu`; it is an instance and holds a reference to the `_Inner` class. The local name `_Inner` is another reference to that class. No other references to these objects exist elsewhere. So when `AppendToMenu` exits, all its locals are cleared, the reference counts to `cl` and `_Inner` drop to 0 and are cleared.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: re: styleguide: method names should be lower_case_with_underscores.

Comment: Also put spaces between parameters/arguments (or at least be consistent) and avoid multi-line statements. Not exactly a style issue, but I would consider `raise NotImplementedError` rather than `pass` in `Base`, too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think I got my answer (you could write as an anwer :) Is this preferable to the second approach for any reason (the `__init__(self, outer)`). Re: style [mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id35) - legacy code

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `raise NotImplementedError`- yes I do it this (this example is stripped down) - consistency on spaces is also due to editing legacy code - noise in the diffs. I thought of addding to the question an :ignore style: notice actually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither method will lead to leaks.

The lifetime of Python objects is governed by reference counting; if there are no references left, the object is removed. In all cases here are the instances and classes in your `Outer.AppendToMenu()` method only referenced by locals, and will not lead to leaks.

In both your cases, the counts for the class and instance are as follows:

- `class _Inner` creates the class, ref count is 1 (the local name `_inner`)
- `cl = _Inner()` creates the instance, ref count for the instance is 1, the `_Inner` class reference goes up to 2 as the instance references its class.
- The `Outer.AppendToMenu()` method exits, and the locals are cleared. `_Inner` and `cl` are cleared, decrementing their reference counts by 1 to 1 and 0 respectively. The `cl` instance is removed, taking with it the remaining reference to the `_Inner` class, so it is deleted too.

The closure over the reference to the `Outer` instance (through `_leak` / `self`) is never used, so no additional references to the `Outer` instance are created.

Personally, I'd pick the closure option here, provided I couldn't first remove the need to use a local class object in that method in the first place.

Comment: The cl instance is appended to a menu - let's hope that the menu clears its appended items when destroyed (wx)